# Get value in Map by name

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

This should be a simple one, but I'm having no luck.

I'm trying to log the authorization headers from a HTTP call.

```
console.log(headers);
```

gives me this map:

```
Map(9) {"date" => Array(1), "server" => Array(1), "authorization" => Array(1), "transfer-encoding" => Array(1), "content-type" => Array(1), …}
```

How do I get to the "authorization" header? 
I have tried:

```
console.log(headers.authorization);
console.log(headers[3]);
```

both of which return undefined

Comment: `headers.get('authorization')`

Comment: When everything else fails, read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Map` objects are not accessed in the same way that standard Javascript `{}` objects are. You need to use the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) and [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) methods:

```
console.log(headers.get('authorization'));
```